# Can i increase speed of array multiplication in python3

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, performance, numpy

I need to speed up my below simple code. I already use numba and pypy, execution time takes nearly 0.00018 sec. However i need to increase execution time. Is there any way to do it ??

**Edit-1**

I have a huge matrix like 250000x6000. For each element i have to run below code. I use parallel processing with 10 cores. It means that (250000*6000*0.00018 sec / 10) about 7 or 8 hours.

**Edit-2**:
  For example: 
  i goes from 0 to 3000
  Bn is 3001x1 float array
  value,part and normx are float scalars
  leg is 3001x1 float array

```
i = np.arange(Lmin,Lmax+1)
kernel = np.sum(((2*i+1)/part)*((value)**(i+1))*leg[i]*Bn[i]*((i-1)/normx))
```

What i tried so far (the fastest one)

```
 @njit
 def trial(normx,Lmin,Lmax,Bn,)
     kernel = 0
     part = something*4*np.pi
     value = some value/normx
     leg = some.funtions()
     for i in range(Lmin,Lmax+1)
         kernel += ((2*i+1)/part)*((value)**(i+1))*leg[i]*Bn[i]
 return(kernel)
```

Comment: How are you measuring your execution time? How big are the arrays? Why do you think 1/5 of a millisecond is too much - how fast do you need the code to be and why? Are you considering the time to start up the Python environment - maybe the time to start the program dominates your execution time? Is multithreading an option?

Comment: 1) I used time library in python. Like nw = time.time() and print(time.time()-nw)
2) Arrays are generally lower than 3000.
3) Because i compute this function for every data in my code. And it tooks 5 hour.
4) If i speed up 10 times or more it will be so fine for my work.

I also use multithreading however all code directly related this simple part. And so sorry i an new person. It was my mistake not reading question checlist.

Comment: Give a complete verifiable and realistic (array sizes and dtypes) example. Also add what you have tried so far.

Comment: I tried to edit and explain it. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplications aren't time consuming in this calculation. But the exponentiation `((value)**(i+1))` is very costly and likely not necessary. It is also not clear if you use global variables in your function. If so, avoid it.

**Original implementation**

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy")
def trial_orig(part,value,Lmin,Lmax,Bn,leg):
    kernel = 0.
    for i in range(0,Lmax+1):
        kernel += ((2*i+1)/part)*((value)**(i+1))*leg[i]*Bn[i]
    return kernel
```

**Avoiding the exponentiation**

Please note that multiplying `fact` repeatedly with itself is only algebraically the same as directly calculating with exponentiation. Since this is numerical math the results may slightly differ.

```
@nb.njit(fastmath=True,error_model="numpy")
def trial_mod(part,value,Lmin,Lmax,Bn,leg):
    #I assume that Lmin is always >0
    assert Lmin>=0.
    kernel = 0.
    fact=value**(Lmin+1)
    for i in range(Lmin,Lmax):
        kernel += ((2*i+1)/part)*fact*leg[i]*Bn[i]
        fact*=value
    return kernel
```

**Timings**

```
leg=np.random.rand(3001)
Bn=np.random.rand(3001)
Lmin=0
Lmax=3000
part=15.
value=0.8

%timeit trial_orig(part,value,Lmin,Lmax,Bn,leg)
100 µs ± 1.11 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit trial_mod(part,value,Lmin,Lmax,Bn,leg)
4.25 µs ± 21.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Comment: You are amazing man. Your answer solved my time problem and taught me to look at it from a different angle. Thanks for everything. Best regards.