# Numba jit warnings interpretation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, recursion, numba

I have defined the following recursive array generator and am using Numba jit to try and accelerate the processing (based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4407984/is-it-possible-to-vectorize-recursive-calculation-of-a-numpy-array-where-each-el))

```py
@jit("float32[:](float32,float32,intp)", nopython=False, nogil=True)
def calc_func(a, b, n):
    res = np.empty(n, dtype="float32")
    res[0] = 0
    for i in range(1, n):
        res[i] = a * res[i - 1] + (1 - a) * (b ** (i - 1))
    return res
a = calc_func(0.988, 0.9988, 5000)
```

I am getting a bunch of warnings/errors that I do not quite get. Would appreciate help in explaining them and making them disappear in order to (I'm assuming) speed up the calculation even more.

Here they are below :

> NumbaWarning: 
>   Compilation is falling back to object mode WITH looplifting enabled because Function "calc_func" failed type inference due to: Invalid use of Function() with argument(s) of type(s): (int64, dtype=Literalstr)
>    * parameterized
>
> In definition 0:
>       All templates rejected with literals.
>
> In definition 1:
>       All templates rejected without literals.
>   This error is usually caused by passing an argument of a type that is unsupported by the named function.
>
> [1] During: resolving callee type: Function()
>
> [2] During: typing of call at `res = np.empty(n, dtype="float32")`
>
> File "thenameofmyscript.py", line 71:

```py
def calc_func(a, b, n):
    res = np.empty(n, dtype="float32")
    ^
```

> @jit("float32:", nopython=False, nogil=True)
>
> thenameofmyscript.py:69: NumbaWarning: 
>   Compilation is falling back to object mode WITHOUT looplifting enabled because Function "calc_func" failed type inference due to: cannot determine Numba type of `<class 'numba.dispatcher.LiftedLoop'>`
>
> File "thenameofmyscript.py", line 73:

```py
def calc_func(a, b, n):
        <source elided>
        res[0] = 0
        for i in range(1, n):
        ^
```

> @jit("float32:", nopython=False, nogil=True)
>
> H:\projects\decay-optimizer\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py:742: NumbaWarning: Function "calc_func" was compiled in object mode without forceobj=True, but has lifted loops.
>
> File "thenameofmyscript.py", line 70:

```py
@jit("float32[:](float32,float32,intp)", nopython=False, nogil=True)
    def calc_func(a, b, n):
    ^
```

> self.func_ir.loc))
>
> H:\projects\decay-optimizer\venv\lib\site-packages\numba\compiler.py:751: NumbaDeprecationWarning: 
>   Fall-back from the nopython compilation path to the object mode compilation path has been detected, this is deprecated behaviour.
>
> File "thenameofmyscript.py", line 70:

```py
@jit("float32[:](float32,float32,intp)", nopython=False, nogil=True)
    def calc_func(a, b, n):
    ^
```

> warnings.warn(errors.NumbaDeprecationWarning(msg, self.func_ir.loc))
>
> thenameofmyscript.py:69: NumbaWarning: Code running in object mode won't allow parallel execution despite nogil=True.
>     @jit("float32:", nopython=False, nogil=True)

Comment: 1) Use njit or nopython=True -> this will yield to an error (fallback to object mode is deprecated anyway). 2) This is wrong syntax: `np.empty(n, dtype="float32")` change it to `np.empty(n, dtype=np.float32)` as you would normally do in numpy. 3) You usually don't need to specify the datatypes. You can completely omit this declaration. `"float32[:](float32,float32,intp)"`

Comment: that did the trick thank you very much. It doesn't make it faster to give the signature of the function ? the type inference is good enough ? If you want to post an answer I'll validate it.

Comment: No a signature isn't necessary. This question is somehow related to this one https://stackoverflow.com/a/57062221/4045774 (the costly expenentiation may be avoidable) But I would highly recommend to use float64.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### 1. Optimize the function (algebraic simplification)

Modern CPUs are quite fast at additions, subtractions and multiplications. Operations like exponentiation, should be avoided when possible.

**Example**

In this example I replaced the costly exponentiation by a simple multiplication. Simplifications like that can lead to quite high speedups, but also may change the result.

At first your implementation (float64) without any signatures, I will treat this later on another simple example.

```
#nb.jit(nopython=True) is a shortcut for @nb.njit()
@nb.njit()
def calc_func_opt_1(a, b, n):
    res = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)
    fact=b
    res[0] = 0.
    res[1] = a * res[0] + (1. - a) *1.
    res[2] = a * res[1] + (1. - a) * fact
    for i in range(3, n):
        fact*=b
        res[i] = a * res[i - 1] + (1. - a) * fact
    return res
```

Also a good idea is to use scalars where possible.

```
@nb.njit()
def calc_func_opt_2(a, b, n):
    res = np.empty(n, dtype=np.float64)
    fact_1=b
    fact_2=0.
    res[0] = fact_2
    fact_2=a * fact_2 + (1. - a) *1.
    res[1] = fact_2
    fact_2 = a * fact_2 + (1. - a) * fact_1
    res[2]=fact_2
    for i in range(3, n):
        fact_1*=b
        fact_2= a * fact_2 + (1. - a) * fact_1
        res[i] = fact_2
    return res
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit a = calc_func(0.988, 0.9988, 5000)
222 µs ± 2.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
%timeit a = calc_func_opt_1(0.988, 0.9988, 5000)
22.7 µs ± 45.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit a = calc_func_opt_2(0.988, 0.9988, 5000)
15.3 µs ± 35.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

### 2. Are signatures recommendable?

In Ahead of time mode (AOT) signatures are necessary, but not in the usual JIT mode. The example above is not SIMD- vectorizable. So you won't see much positive nor negative effects of a possibly not optimal declaration of in- and outputs.
Let's look at another example.

```
#Numba is able to SIMD-vectorize this loop if 
#a,b,res are contigous arrays
@nb.njit(fastmath=True)
def some_function_1(a,b):
    res=np.empty_like(a)
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        res[i]=a[i]**2+b[i]**2
    return res

@nb.njit("float64[:](float64[:],float64[:])",fastmath=True)
def some_function_2(a,b):
    res=np.empty_like(a)
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        res[i]=a[i]**2+b[i]**2
    return res

a=np.random.rand(10_000)
b=np.random.rand(10_000)

#Example for non contiguous input
#a=np.random.rand(10_000)[0::2]
#b=np.random.rand(10_000)[0::2]

%timeit res=some_function_1(a,b)
5.59 µs ± 36.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
%timeit res=some_function_2(a,b)
9.36 µs ± 47.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

**Why is the version with signatures slower?**

Let's have a closer look on the signatures.

```
some_function_1.nopython_signatures
#[(array(float64, 1d, C), array(float64, 1d, C)) -> array(float64, 1d, C)]
some_function_2.nopython_signatures
#[(array(float64, 1d, A), array(float64, 1d, A)) -> array(float64, 1d, A)]
#this is equivivalent to 
#"float64[::1](float64[::1],float64[::1])"
```

If the memory layout is unknown at compile time, it is often impossible to SIMD- vectorize the algorithm. Of course you can explicitly declare C-contigous arrays, but the function wont work anymore for non contigous inputs, which is normally not intended.

Comment: Amazing thank you very much. I do not understand why the use of scalars makes a difference. Optically, it looks like you are doing more operations for the exact same result. The fact that it keeps `fact_2` in memory makes the difference ?